# Accessing Tasks with Graph API

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently trying to access my microsoft task from a python application by using the following code:

```py
client = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)

# First, try to lookup an access token in cache
token_result = client.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)

# If the token is available in cache, save it to a variable
if token_result:
  access_token = 'Bearer ' + token_result['access_token']
  print('Access token was loaded from cache')

# If the token is not available in cache, acquire a new one from Azure AD and save it to a variable
if not token_result:
  token_result = client.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
  access_token = 'Bearer ' + token_result['access_token']
#   print('New access token was acquired from Azure AD')

# print(access_token)


url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ae444444-4444-448f-be95-f58390836cca/todo/lists'
headers = {
    'Authorization': access_token
}

graph_result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

print(graph_result.json())
```

However, I always get a `accessDenied` response.
Although I have set the Task.Read.All API permission.

[permissions screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KOzt.png)

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Application permissions are not supported for To Do Tasks requests at this moment, you need delegated permissions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todo-list-lists?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: Thank you. Never checked that. I thought that because there is an api permission for applications to read tasks it should be supported.